# hasNextLine() always returns false

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, spell-checking

I'm trying to make a spell checker and going to open the words in .txt file in a linked list but hasNextLine() always returns false.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class backEnd {
    String string;
    String[] splitted;

    public backEnd(String s){
        string=s;
    }
    public void splitter(){
        splitted =string.split(" ");
        for (int x=0; x<splitted.length; x++){
            System.out.println(splitted[x]);
        }
    }




    public void spellChecker(){
        Serializable data = new String[100];
        LinkedList<String> l=new LinkedList<String>();

        File f= new File("WordDict.txt");
        if(!f.exists())
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            FileInputStream Fis=new FileInputStream(f);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(Fis);
            System.out.println("Check outside nextline");
```

this is the point where it should take words line by line from .txt file but it always breaks the loop.

```
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                    System.out.println("Check in nextline");
                    data = sc.nextLine();
                    l.add( (String) data);
                }
                sc.close();
             }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
                fnf.printStackTrace();
             }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
             }
            int x=0;
            int y=0;
            while(x<splitted.length){
                while(y<l.size()){
                    if(l.get(y)==splitted[x]){
                        System.out.println("Matched.");
                    y++;
                    }`enter code here`
                }
                System.out.println("Wrong spelling of: "+splitted[x]);
                x++;    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a reader instead of a scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious reason seems to be that the file `WordDict.txt` doesn't exist,
so your code creates it, but it's empty, so it has no next line.

In this code, put a breakpoint on `f.createNewFile()`:

```
    File f= new File("WordDict.txt");
    if(!f.exists())
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        FileInputStream Fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Fis);
        System.out.println("Check outside nextline");
```

Another obvious reason can be that the file exists but it's empty.

Most probably your problem is the first one, and your confusion comes from your assumption of the execution directory. That is, the program is probably not executed where you think. To verify what, change `WordDict.txt` to absolute path.

Comment: Thanks janos! its my stupidity that I misspelled the file name.

Comment: But still, it isn't working as I want it to. Its reading from the file but not comparing.. I've modified the code a bit.. As i'm new to stackoverflow, can you guide how can I show you the new code?

Comment: It's a new code, and a new problem, so post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

sc.hasNextLine() returns true just because is a Empty file!!! Try to write something on it.

In addition your while loop is infinite and a not correct compair (string == string is wrong):

```
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        while(x<splitted.length){
            while(y<l.size()){
                if(l.get(y)==splitted[x]){
                    System.out.println("Matched.");
                y++;
                }`enter code here`
            }
            System.out.println("Wrong spelling of: "+splitted[x]);
            x++;    
        }
```

This loop maybe should be something like this:

```
                int x=0;
                int y=0;
                while(x<splitted.length){
                    while(y<l.size()){

                        if(l.get(y).equals(splitted[x])){
                            System.out.println("l.get("+ y +") is "+ l.get(y) +", splitted["+x+"] is "+ splitted[x]);
                            System.out.println("Matched.");
                        y++;
                        x++;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Wrong spelling of: "+splitted[x]);
                            y++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```